# How to filter images on GAE?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

I'm working on python google app engine application,i'm using python2.5, i want to deal with images on GAE(filter images), initially i tried wit PIL library and i installed it successfully and i tested it and it works correctly on my computer,but when i test it on localhost(run on GAE), i have an error that `NotImplementedError: Unable to find the Python PIL library`,then i tried to deal with images using Images Python API , as in this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview, and i tested resizing images service,and it works correctly,but the main application that i want is to filter the images,the question is :if this service(image filtering) supported in Images Python API in GAE?and if not how can i filter images on GAE?i saw that this service available in PIL and i tested it,but this library is not supported by GAE in python2.5

**EDIT:**

I tried to use python2.7 to use PIL library on GAE as https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Configuring_Libraries, i installed PIL 1.1.7, and configured the **app.yaml** file as:

```
application: app_id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"
```

now how can i use this library in main.py page?i tried as `from PIL import Image`, buth the problem still as:

```
No module named PIL 
      args = ('No module named PIL',) 
      message = 'No module named PIL'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. What makes you think you installed PIL successfully if the images API can't find it? 2. PIL is supported on App Engine, if you use the Python 2.7 runtime.

Comment: @Wooble:i tested it,it's works correctly as python run application,but when i run the application on localhost as GAE run, i got the above error(i used python 2.5,if i use python 2.7,does PIL supported by GAE??).

Comment: How are you running dev_appserver.py? Are you using the same Python installation where PIL works correctly?

Comment: @Wooble : i tested this code for example to check PIL : http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216637/resize-an-image-python, and it's worked correctly for resizing images,but on GAE i have that NotImplementedError: Unable to find the Python PIL library

Comment: @Wooble:i tried to use python2.7 and i installed PIL for it and edited the app.yaml,now how to use this library in the python page?Thank you

Answer (score 6):

With python2.5, PIL itself is not available. The built-in [images module](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview) uses an API that looks like PIL, and using the SDK (on your computer) PIL is used for compatibility, so you'll need to install it. The docs (previous link) have instructions for how to do this on windows/mac/linux.

With python2.7, you need to [configure your app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Configuring_Libraries) to use the app-engine version of PIL once deployed. Locally, again you'll need to install PIL yourself, outside of your application folder.

Answer (score 3):

there is no `import PIL` its `import Image`

Comment: i tried import Image but this gave me error,so i tried as import PIL

Comment: @Greg: import Image not define(this is the error),i must write as From PIL import Image